# What is the value of this product Viete type

Tags: calculus

I would like to prove $$\prod _{k=0}^{\infty } \frac{\left(2 \cos \left(\pi  5^{-k-1}\right)+2 \cos \left(2 \pi  5^{-k-1}\right)+1\right)^2}{\left(2 \cos \left(2\ 5^{-k-1} z\right)+2 \cos \left(4\ 5^{-k-1} z\right)+1\right)^2}=\frac{4 z^2 \csc ^2(z)}{\pi ^2}$$
and I get $$\prod _{k=0}^{m-1} \frac{\left(2 \cos \left(\pi  5^{-k-1}\right)+2 \cos \left(2 \pi  5^{-k-1}\right)+1\right)^2}{\left(2 \cos \left(2\ 5^{-k-1} z\right)+2 \cos \left(4\ 5^{-k-1} z\right)+1\right)^2}=\csc ^2\left(\frac{\pi  5^{-m}}{2}\right) \csc ^2(z) \sin ^2\left(5^{-m} z\right)$$ maybe proving m tend to infinity

Comment: Have you tried taking the limit of the RHS of the 2nd equation as $m\to\infty$?

Comment: Thanks @David H  works almost in mathematica

Answer (score 1):

The cosecant is the reciprocal of the sine, so all you need to do is take the limit of

$$
\frac{\sin ax}{\sin bx}
$$

for $x\to0$, which is $\frac ab$ (from Taylor expansion or L'Hôpital).